# Can't move neither mp3 nor jpg with Files.move in java

Tags: java, file, move

I just finished reading another question of the same type but unfortunaetly it didn't help me a lot.

I have a problem with moving files like mp3 and jpg to another folder which i created before trying to move those files.

Here's my code:

```
public class FilesSorter {
   private String extension;

   public FilesSorter(String ext) {
      this.setExtension(ext);
   }

   public void setExtension(String extension) {
      this.extension = extension;
   }

   public void sortIt(Path path, Path FileName) {
      String StringPath = path.toString();

      switch (this.extension) {
        case "folder":
            return;
        case "txt":
            File folderDocs = new File(StringPath + ("\\Documents"));
            if (!folderDocs.exists()) {
                folderDocs.mkdir();
            }
            Path sourceDocs = path.resolve(FileName);
            Path targetDocs = folderDocs.toPath().resolve(FileName);
            try {
                Files.move(sourceDocs, targetDocs, ATOMIC_MOVE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Moving failed.");
            }
            break;
        case "mp3":
        case "wma":
        case "ogg":
            File folderMsc = new File(StringPath + ("\\Music"));
            if (!folderMsc.exists()) {
                System.out.println("created folder");
                folderMsc.mkdir();
            }
            Path sourceMsc = path.resolve(FileName);
            Path targetMsc = folderMsc.toPath().resolve(FileName);
            System.out.println(sourceMsc);
            System.out.println(targetMsc);
            try {
                Files.move(sourceMsc, targetMsc, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Moving failed.");
            }
            break;
       ...
}
```

And the fragment where I'm calling that method:

```
while (true) {
            key = FolderMonitor.take();

            Kind<?> tmp;

            for (WatchEvent<?> EventsInFolder : key.pollEvents()) {
                tmp = EventsInFolder.kind();

                if (tmp == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    Path RecentlyCreatedPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) EventsInFolder).context();
                    System.out.println("New Path created: " + RecentlyCreatedPath);
                    type = this.giveMeType(String.valueOf(RecentlyCreatedPath));
                    this.actWithFile(type, RecentlyCreatedPath);
                } else if (tmp == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    System.out.println("Path deleted: " + ((WatchEvent<Path>) EventsInFolder).context());
                } else if (tmp == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!key.reset()) {
                break;
            }
            timeThen = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(timeThen - timeNow > 120000) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

As I've said, when I try to move txt it works, when I try to move mp3 it says "Moving failed."

Thank you all in advance for answering my question or giving some other tips where to find such information.

EDIT: Here's the code where I actually call the sortIt method (sorry for not making it earlier).

```
private void actWithFile (String type, Path pathToFile) {
    FilesSorter fs = new FilesSorter(type);
    fs.sortIt(this.PathDirectory, pathToFile);
}
```

Comment: Change `System.out.println("Moving failed.");` to `System.out.println("Moving failed: "+ e.getMessagE());` to know the Exception message.

Comment: Ok, it says:  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

How could it be if I'm not playing that file?

Comment: Did you closed the stream after reading it?

Comment: I don't use any streams. Actually I don't really read or open the file. I just take its name, cut the extension and act depending on its extension.